# How does one escape policy variables in AWS CloudFormation YAML templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have been trying to write a number of my AWS CloudFormation templates in the YAML format.

I have been having issues with CloudFormation trying to parse IAM policy variables, such as `${aws:username}`, in conjunction with substitutions. An example is the following:

```
CommonUserGroup:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Group
  Properties:
    GroupName: Common
    Path: /project/
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: ClusterPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: 2012-10-17
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy"
              Resource: "*"
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: "iam:ChangePassword"
              Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/${aws:username}'
```

When the CloudFormation template is used to try and create a stack the following error is returned:

```
Template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [aws:username] in the Resources block of the template
```

If I manually specify the username, rather than using a policy variable, like:

```
'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/bob'
```

Then the error goes away.

Is there a way that one can escape policy variables such that CloudFormation doesn't try and parse them as part of the template?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a bit of searching I came across the following Reddit post which mentions the same problem: [Creating No MFA No Access policy via YAML template - substitution issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5lfthg/creating_no_mfa_no_access_policy_via_yaml/)

A reply to this thread referenced the following AWS CloudFormation documentation: [Filter View: Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html), which states:

> To write a dollar sign and curly braces (${}) literally, add an exclamation point (!) after the open curly brace, such as ${!Literal}. AWS CloudFormation resolves this text as ${Literal}.

This can be used to escape policy variables.

So in the example in my question, `${aws:username}` can be escaped in the YAML as `${!aws:username}`.